# Embedding tab bar to top of screen iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want to design a page with tab bar on top of it.In some articles of this site.(i missed urls) i found that this is not a common way and the question gets some down rate.

The question is this: whethere having a design like this may cause that apple not approve the application on his store?

Comment: This will not cause any promlems with application verification

Comment: From a user point of view, the page looks a bit confusing. Maybe you could consider re-designing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it doesn't make Apple reject your app, think of the users not being used to the tab bar being at the top and how that is going to affect how well the app does in the Store.

Every platform has its own design patterns and there is a reason for that. If you stick to them there is a higher chance that the first-time users have an easier time using your app, which results in a higher chance that they keep using it. If they don't know how to use it or find it hard, they will move to another one.

Take a look at the [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and apply them. It will do good.